# How can I specify multiple FHIR resources in 1 FHIR resource in Java

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am totally new to FHIR and was trying to bundle a number of resources into 1 resource and send it as JSON file.

For example I have 3 Patient resources I want to put in 1 Resource like List. The List resource did not seem to have what I needed.

Is this possible ? How can this be done.

Thanks for any help
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, for just a general bundle of resources, you'd use the json equivalent of an atom feed. There's an example here:

http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/query-example-response.json

and the spec for that is here:

http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/formats.htm#json-bundles

The List resource is specifically for clinical and workflow lists such as medication list. You could use a list for this, but probably it's not what you want - you don't really say, but I'd guess that the JSON atom equivalent what you are looking for

Comment: Hi Grahame, Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example of how to use the List resource for a medication list ? How do you add multiple medications or vaccines into 1 List Resource ?

Comment: http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/list-example.xml.htm - this is an example of a list, though that's a problem list. A medication list would have links to medication resources instead

Comment: David Hay has a nice blog entry for this.  See http://fhirblog.com/2013/10/31/representing-a-patients-list-of-medications-in-fhir/